# How to close a web site visited using w3m on Termux on Android?

Tags: terminal, terminal-emulator, w3m

I installed w3m on Termux on Android and then opened google.com using the statement `w3m https://google.com/`. I would like know how to get out of w3m back to the Terminal window.[image: this is how the screen appeara.]

Answer (score 4):

Simply use 'q'(without quotes)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For Exiting the w3m Browser and going back to the Terminal window.

Press CTRL + Q on your keyboard and you will be back on your terminal window.